# MySQL - cannot add foreign key

Tags: mysql, key, addition

I have a table in MySQL InnoDB created like that:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` enum('MANUAL','FACEBOOK') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'MANUAL',
  `role` enum('COOK','HOST','ALL') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ALL',
  `about_me` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `food_preferences` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cooking_experience` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `with_friend` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Next I tried adding a table with such a statement (no foreign keys added while creating the table as had problem with that):

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `from` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `to` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp_sent` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `timestamp_read` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Having tables created, I need to finally add foreign keys on `'from'` and `'to'` fields referencing `'users'.'id'` field:

```
ALTER TABLE `messages` 
  ADD CONSTRAINT `messages_users_fk`
  FOREIGN KEY (`from` , `to` )
  REFERENCES `users` (`id` , `id` )
  ON DELETE SET NULL
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
, ADD INDEX `messages_users_fk_idx` (`from` ASC, `to` ASC)
```

The error I get is:

> ERROR: Error 1822: Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'messages_users_fk' in the referenced table 'users'.

But 'users' table has a `PRIMARY` index on `'id'`...

Also tried to make a smaller step and add foreign key just for `'from'` field:

```
ALTER TABLE `messages` 
  ADD CONSTRAINT `messages_users_fk`
  FOREIGN KEY (`from` )
  REFERENCES `users` (`id` )
  ON DELETE SET NULL
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
, ADD INDEX `messages_users_fk_idx` (`from` ASC) ;
```

The error is slightly different:

> ERROR: Error 1825: Failed to add the foreign key constraint on table 'messages'. Incorrect options in FOREIGN KEY constraint 'cook4food/messages_users_fk'.

The types of the fields are the same (`bigint(20) NOT NULL`) as it was suggested as the cause of the problem in other StackOverflow threads. My tables are not partitioned (MySQL manual states this as a limitation for having foreign key constraints in InnoDB). The `'messages'` table stores no rows currently, so data stored can't be the issue in any manner. I'm stuck, please help.

Comment: +1 Lovely to see actual `CREATE TABLE` statements to play with them :)

Answer (score 16):

If you have the appropriate privileges, you can issue this query:

```
SHOW ENGINE innodb STATUS
```

... which will tell you (among some other info) the exact details of the error:

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
130311 13:30:06 Error in foreign key constraint of table test/#sql-71c_6:

  FOREIGN KEY (`from` , `to` )
  REFERENCES `users` (`id` , `id` )
  ON DELETE SET NULL
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
, ADD INDEX `messages_users_fk_idx` (`from` ASC, `to` ASC):
You have defined a SET NULL condition though some of the
columns are defined as NOT NULL.
```

On parent record deletion, you can't make child record NULL because the columns are `NOT NULL`:

```
  `from` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `to` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
```

**Edit:** Additionally, I can't see the purpose of a single composite key. I think you want two single keys instead.

Comment: StackOverflow community helpful and quick as always :-). I can see my mistake now, thank you!

Comment: Any ideas if `SHOW ENGINE innodb STATUS` doesn't show LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR?

Comment: Thank U ! +1 Alavaro. You save me froma second night ! Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks, @Álvaro González. I could find my mistake fast.

Answer (score 0):

`REFERENCES`users`(`id`,`id`)`

You are attempting to create an invalid foreign key (id, id).   The columns involved in a composite index (one involving more than one column) cannot be the same column, repeated.  At least I have never seen that.

Create two separate foreign keys, one for FROM and the other for TO, each one pointing back at users.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about the difference between these two approaches. Separate foreign keys are what I really need. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As we have seen,

You can not define SET NULL in child records when the child columns `from` and `to` are not null.

So if you try to create the foreign keys with the following 2 statements, you should have the foreign keys in `messages` table.

1>

```
ALTER TABLE `messages`  ADD CONSTRAINT `messages_users_from_fk`   FOREIGN KEY (`from` )   REFERENCES `users` (`id` )  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, ADD INDEX `messages_users_fk_idx` (`from` ASC) ;
```

and

2>

```
ALTER TABLE `messages`  ADD CONSTRAINT `messages_users_to_fk`   FOREIGN KEY (`to` )   REFERENCES `users` (`id` )  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, ADD INDEX `messages_users_fk_to_idx` (`to` ASC) ;
```

Hope these statements help you.