# I keep getting DatabaseError: (1825, "Failed to add the foreign key constraint on table...)

Tags: mysql, django, django-south

I have an existing model/table `Foo`:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    foo_id = models.CharField(max_length=64,
                              null=False,
                              primary_key=True,
                              unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False)
    ...

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.pk

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'foo'
```

Now, I want to add a new model/table `FooBar`:

```
class FooBar(models.Model):
    foobar_id = models.AutoField(max_length=11,
                                 null=False,
                                 primary_key=True)
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    bar = models.TextField()
    ...

    class Meta:
        app_lable = 'foo'
```

When I do a `./manage.py schemamigration foo --auto` and `./manage.py migrate foo`, I get an error:

```
Error in migration: schematicdb:0013_auto__add_foobar
DatabaseError: (1825, "Failed to add the foreign key constraint on table 'foo_foobar'.
Incorrect options in FOREIGN KEY constraint foo_db/foo_id_refs_foo_id_1e8ab51a'")
```

Using MySQL with Django 1.5.4 and South 0.8.2 for this.

I've tried the ff. but to no avail:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': 'SET foreign_key_checks=0;',
        },
        'DEFAULT_STORAGE_ENGINE': 'InnoDB',
    }
}
```

So right now, I don't know where to start checking.

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338582/mysql-cannot-add-foreign-key